# How can I get these two pgfplots to be exactly aligned?

Tags: pgfplots

I have two pgfplots plots that have exactly the same width as far as their displayed data goes, but have different x-label widths and y-label widths.

How can I get them to align such that the part where the data is displayed is on the same x-position on the document?

**first plot:**

```
   ^
200|
150|
100| some data
 50|
 --|----------->
   | 50 100 150
```

**second plot:**

```
      ^
200000|
150000|
100000| some data
 50000|
    --|----------->
      | 50 100 150
```

Here's how they align in my document (using `\centering`):

```
     ^
  200|
  150|
  100| some data
   50|
   --|----------->
     | 50 100 150

      ^
200000|
150000|
100000| some data
 50000|
    --|----------->
      | 50 100 150
```

Here is how I want them to align (but they still have to kind of be in the center of the document):

```
      ^
   200|
   150|
   100| some data
    50|
    --|----------->
      | 50 100 150

      ^
200000|
150000|
100000| some data
 50000|
    --|----------->
      | 50 100 150
```

I have an idea on how this could work:
Is there some option (I searched online but didn't find anything) that tells pgfplot to kind of have "floating" labels?

(I am rendering these pgfplots as seperate pdf files and then I include them in my main tex-file, because somehow I can't get them to externalize, but that is a different story)

Comment: Does the post [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69928](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69928/110998) help? Or [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99599](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99599/110998)? Or [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348484](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348484/110998)?

Comment: No, these don't work, because the plots are separate pdf files.
However, I got it working by just extending the axis and then it worked fine.